# Prototype Carousel

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs, carousel

I'm trying to integrate carousel functionality with my Magento store, but failing miserably thus far.

I've looked into owl carousel (http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) but couldn't manage to integrate it with Magento. I think it could be due to the fact that owl carousel is based on jquery whereas Magento only natively supports prototype-js, not jquery. I'm not too sure about the noConflict procedure.

Would really appreciate a step-by-step guide on integrating either Owl Carousel, or perhaps an alternative Prototype-JS carousel **with Magento**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer pertains to the OPs wish to use Owl Carousel - it does not address the question of using a carousel with PrototypeJs**

You will need to add jQuery if you plan on using OwlCarousel.  While it pains me to add a second library next to Prototype, I have used Owl Carousel in the past on Magento installs as well.

1. Either Link a CDN copy of jQuery and add it to your theme's head.phtml file or add jQuery to your skin/js folder and add it to your layout.

E.g. in page.xml (or wherever you need to load jQuery) - if under the `default` handle, this will load it globally on your front end.

```
    <reference name="head">
        ...
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/vendor/jQuery/jQuery.1.11.min.js</name></action>
       ...
    </reference>
```

2. Add the Owl Library in a similar fashion (the default handle will load this globally, but you could easily restrict this to only applicable pages) I placed owl in my `skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/js/vendor/` folder using the example below.

E.g. on page.xml - or appropriate layout document

```
 <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/vendor/OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>js/vendor/OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>js/vendor/OwlCarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

3. Implement owl with the template you wish to use it, or better, add a separate script to handle the functionality and add it to your layout.

E.g. if you were to add it directly to the `.phtml` file where your carousel content is loaded. Obviously the selectors are for demonstration only.

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var brandSlides = $("#hero-slides");

            $(brandSlides).owlCarousel({
                 ... OWL OPTIONS ...
            });
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: prototype and jQuery dont play well together

Comment: I addressed this caveat in my answer, @AlanSutherland.  I am not aware of a good, responsive Prototype carousel.   If properly isolated, jQuery and Prototype can sit side-by-side without issue aside from the higher payload.